# What is the difference between char* temp[2] vs char** temp?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here's my code:

```
char* temp[2];
char** temp2;

temp[0] = "hellowkfuewoif2o4ig";
temp[1] = "hgjfthe";
temp2[0] = "hello";
temp2[1] = "hello2leh";
```

Initializing the elements of `temp` doesn't create an error, but initializing the elements of `temp2` creates an error. I believe `char* temp[2]` is a pointer to 2 char pointers, but I don't know if that's right. I know that `temp2` and its elements need memory allocated dynamically, but why doesn't `temp` need that?

I was expecting the following code to throw an error, but it never did.

```
temp[0] = "hellowkfuewoif2o4ig";
temp[1] = "hgjfthe";
```

Comment: Don't you mean `temp` and not `name(s)`

Comment: My bad. You're right! I'll fix it.

Comment: `char* T[]` means T is a pointer to an array of `char*` pointers. `char **` is the same thing but said in a different way like it is a `pointer` to a array of fixed-sized pointers which are `char *`

Comment: @RequireKeys That is not correct. `char *T[]` does not make `T` a pointer of any type unless you put it in a parameter list of a function which is not the case here.

Comment: @Gerhardh So you're saying that `T` in `char *T[]`  only works like a pointer, i.e. allow derefs when it's part of a function argument of a function prototype? That is so weird

Comment: @RequireKeys The main difference between a pointer and an array is not whether you can take the identifier and dereference it. That is possible in both cases as the array variable name will decay to a pointer. But the main difference is that an array provides memory for its elements while the pointer only provides storage for 1 address. That is not weird. These are the very basics of arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *temp[2];
```

declares an array of 2 pointers. You can then assign each of the array elements.

```
char **temp2;
```

declares a single pointer, but doesn't initialize it. There's no memory for the contents of the array. You have to allocate memory and assign it to the pointer.

```
temp2 = malloc(2 * sizeof *temp2);
```

Comment: I just saw your comment. How come doing this `malloc(2 * sizeof *temp2)` achieve the same results as `malloc(2 * sizeof(char*))`?

Comment: Because the size of an expression is the same as the size of the type of the expression. And the type of `*temp2` is `char*`.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `sizeof *variable` in the malloc argument. That way if you change the type of the variable, you don't have to edit the argument to `malloc`, which is an easy thing to forget.

Comment: Ohhhh. Alright, thanks! That part was confusing for a bit. I was thinking `*temp2` meant `char` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`char *temp[2]` is an array of two pointers to `char` values.

`char **temp2` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` value.

The former represents an allocation of memory for two `char` pointers, so assigning values to those pointers is fine.

The latter is an uninitialized pointer, so dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. You would want to initialize this using dynamic memory allocation with a function like `malloc`, but even then you'd want to error check to ensure `malloc` succeeds before making any assignments as your example code has done.

Comment: The former is uninitialized too. Dereferencing those pointers invokes undefined behaviour too.

Comment: Clarified. Thanks.

Comment: The latter represents an allocation of memory one pointer, so assigning a value to that pointer is fine too.